# VueJS loader failing OpenAPI client

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to generate a javascript client to use in a VueJS project,

Generator: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation

generating the client like this:

```
  -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
  -l javascript \
  -o ~/code/snippets/petstore
```

Then linking it to my project with `npm install ../petstore`

I have used the example generated in my code:

```
var SwaggerPetstore = require('swagger_petstore');
var defaultClient = SwaggerPetstore.ApiClient.instance;

// Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: petstore_auth
var petstore_auth = defaultClient.authentications['petstore_auth'];
petstore_auth.accessToken = "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"

var api = new SwaggerPetstore.PetApi()
var body = new SwaggerPetstore.Pet(); // {Pet} Pet object that needs to be added to the store

var callback = function(error, data, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('API called successfully.');
  }
};
api.addPet(body, callback);
```

However when i run npm run serve i get the following error

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     * @readonly
|     */
>     static CollectionFormatEnum = {
|         /**
|          * Comma-separated values. Value: <code>csv</code>

 @ ./node_modules/swagger_petstore/src/index.js 14:0-36 58:0-130:2
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.106:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I understand i need to install a loader to use inside my vue.config.js with, however i'm not sure exactly which loader i need to be using or how to debug it from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you